# Adding information in new rows in between filled rows

Tags: excel, vba, userform

i would like a user form that helps me to add in information on an empty rows. However, the empty rows are found in between rows that are filled. for example row 2 is empty while row 1 and row 3 is filled. Thus i would need a code that is able to run through all the rows and whichever rows is empty, it will be filled by the user form input.
I only manage to come out with this code but it only works on every last row of the columns.

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click() 

 lastrow = Sheets("Programme Status Summary").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(lastrow + 1, "J").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "E").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "C").Value = TextBoxSegment.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "F").Value = TextBoxSummary.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "G").Value = TextBoxAcc1.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "H").Value = TextBoxAcc2.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "I").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "K").Value = TextBoxCountry.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "L").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "M").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "P").Value = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "R").Value = TextBoxSchPar.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "S").Value = TextBoxImpact.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "T").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "U").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "V").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "W").Value = TextBoxListImpt.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "X").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "N").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "O").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "Y").Value = TextBoxRagStatus.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "Z").Value = TextBoxRagCost.Text
Cells(lastrow + 1, "AA").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
End Sub
```

I hope that anyone could help me with this. Would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should go through your rows and check if the cell in column A is empty, starting at row 1. Perhaps you need to adjust those parameters to your needs.

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim wksWork As Worksheet

Set wksWork = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Programme Status Summary")
With wksWork
    lastrow = .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lnglstwor 'starts at Row 1, adjust accordingly
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Or .Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then 'Checks if the first cell of the row isempty
            .Cells(i, "J").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
            .Cells(i, "E").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
            .Cells(i, "C").Value = TextBoxSegment.Text
            .Cells(i, "F").Value = TextBoxSummary.Text
            .Cells(i, "G").Value = TextBoxAcc1.Text
            .Cells(i, "H").Value = TextBoxAcc2.Text
            .Cells(i, "I").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
            .Cells(i, "K").Value = TextBoxCountry.Text
            .Cells(i, "L").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
            .Cells(i, "M").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
            .Cells(i, "P").Value = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
            .Cells(i, "R").Value = TextBoxSchPar.Text
            .Cells(i, "S").Value = TextBoxImpact.Text
            .Cells(i, "T").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
            .Cells(i, "U").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
            .Cells(i, "V").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
            .Cells(i, "W").Value = TextBoxListImpt.Text
            .Cells(i, "X").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
            .Cells(i, "N").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
            .Cells(i, "O").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
            .Cells(i, "Y").Value = TextBoxRagStatus.Text
            .Cells(i, "Z").Value = TextBoxRagCost.Text
            .Cells(i, "AA").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```